# CSS - :Hover doesn't work without absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

The css is suppose to make a caption slide out from the left side along some other CSS3 effects which it does.

However I need to remove `position: absolute;` from `.box img`. However when I do, the `:hover` event on `.box` does not seem to work no more.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unf2azhe/2/)

I commented out the `position: absolute;` in question.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <img class="box-image" src="http://knyz.org/blog/content/images/2015/01/Ghost-vs-WP.png"/>
        <span class="caption scale-caption">
            <h3>Ghost vs Wordpress</h3>
            <p>What is ghost again? Ghost is a free blogging platform like WordPress. Although similar there are key differences which in my mind, make Ghost the go-to blogging platform. Just a Blogging Platform That is the most important difference. Ghost says upfront what they are about and always will be</p>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img class="box-image" src="http://knyz.org/blog/content/images/2015/01/owncloud-registration.jpg"/>
        <span class="caption scale-caption">
            <h3>OwnCloud Registration Script - Fixed!</h3>
            <p>'Bout time! I am really sorry for the long wait. I was very busy and was really not motivated to work on it after it broke for the second time. That said, you shouldn't blame me, blame ownCloud for not making it themselves! The important thing however is that now</p>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
}

.box {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 270px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
}

.box img {
        /*
        position: absolute;/**/
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    width: 100%;
}

    /* Caption Common Style */
.box .caption {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    left: 0;
}

    /** Caption 3: Fade **/
.box .fade-caption, .box .scale-caption {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
    /** Caption 6: Scale **/
.box .scale-caption h3, .box .scale-caption p {
    position: relative;
    left: -200px;
    width: 90%;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

.box .scale-caption h3 {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0ms
        -moz-transition-delay: 0ms
        -o-transition-delay: 0ms
        -ms-transition-delay: 0ms
        transition-delay: 0ms;
}

.box .scale-caption p {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 300ms;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

    /** Fade Caption :hover Behaviour **/
.box:hover .fade-caption, .box:hover .scale-caption {
    opacity: 1;
}
    /** Scale Caption :hover Behaviour **/
.box:hover .box-image {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -o-transform: scale(1.4);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    transform: scale(1.4);
}

.box:hover .scale-caption h3, .box:hover .scale-caption p {
    -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
    -o-transform: translateX(200px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
    transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

How would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: why do you "need" to remove it?

Comment: I am looking at your code in jsfiddle, with and without `position: absolute`, but I am not sure what seems to be going wrong.  What is the layout not doing that you need? Can you explain?  To me it seems okay, so I am missing something.

Comment: @karaokyo In order to use `height: auto` on `.box` later on.

Comment: @MarcAudet With it, a caption with text should slide in over the image.

Comment: Your original jsfiddle works in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome. The proposed solution by Josh Crozier fixes the problem.  The issue is probably due to the differences in how the position offsets are computed in Chrome versus the other browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `top: 0` to `.box .caption`. [**(updated example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/8e88370x/)

When the `img` element was absolutely positioned, it was removed from the normal flow, thus the `.caption` was placed over top of it because it was absolutely positioned too. If you removed the absolute positioning from the `img` element, it becomes part of the flow again, thereby requiring the `.caption` element to be positioned at the top. (thus, `top: 0`, relative to the parent element).

```
.box .caption {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;     /* Added */
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Works finely! However could you explain a bit more in depth what was going on? Edit: nvm, you just edited it. Thank you!

Comment: See, even with this, changing height to auto still does the same thing. I fail to see what your actual problem was.

Comment: @karaokyo I wanted to set the height of `.box` to the image within. However `position: absolute` was standing in the way of that by not being part of the flow. All that matters for me however is that it works.

Comment: The original code worked in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome.  The problem stems from a cross browser issue.

Answer (score 1):

oki dokes, looks like the position of the .caption was sitting below the viewable area of each .box

change

```
.box img {

position: relative;
z-index:50; ...
```

Add

```
.box .caption {
    top: 0; ...
```